# Transferring data via ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I resolve the problem with the format but I have a new problem in the transfer of the data by ajax to my php.

Ajax send data like:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost/test-fullcalendar/php/add_evento.php',
data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end ,
type: "POST",
success: function(json) {
alert('OK');
}
});
```

And add_evento.php receive like:

```
$title=$_POST['title'];

$start=$_POST['start'];

$end=$_POST['end'];
```

It says me 'undefined index' in all of the variables so I included 'isset' in anyone. After that I did an echo of the variables and none receives correctly the data, all of them didn't show anything. I try to changing the data line to:

```
data: {title: title, start: start, end: end},
```

and the method POST to GET and still doesn't working.

How I can check if I sending correctly the data? I'm writing alert(data.title); inside ajax function but don't show anything.

Comment: Did you check the content type?

Answer (score 3):

Your data is incorrect. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/test-fullcalendar/php/add_evento.php',
  data: {"title": title, "start": start, "end": end},
  type: "POST",
  success: function(json) {
    alert('OK');
  }
});
```

If `type: "POST"` you can access data with `$_POST` and if `type: "GET"` you can access with `$_GET`

Answer (score 1):

```
 data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end
```

This should be changed to:

```
 data: {title:title, start:start, end:end}
```

You can also do the call like this:

```
$.post('http://localhost/test-fullcalendar/php/add_evento.php',{title:title, start:start, end:end}, function(json) {
alert('OK');
});
```